# Passing a variable to JQuery submit function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this:

```
$('#id').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    etc etc
```

I want to be able to have this:

```
$('#id' + variable).submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    etc etc
```

I'm not sure what I should do to go about that. The reason for it is that there are many similar forms on the page that get generated dynamically.

I tried doing this and I'm guessing that is just a terrible thing to do but it was all I could think to try as I am not very good with JQuery:

```
function foo(variable){
    $('#id' + variable).submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    etc etc
}
```

But that causes the form to be submitted multiple times.

-edit- to respond to a request:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "process.php",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function(data) { 

            var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
            etc etc do some stuff like show a message (all that works)
```

Comment: Could you post how you submit your form in that submit() function?

Comment: What should contain you variable ? If it's another selector, do not forget to use a comma => $('#id, ' + variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are producing multiple forms with different ID's dynamically, it would probably advantageous if they all used the same `class="preventSubmit"` and your code looked like:

```
$('.preventSubmit').submit(function(e){
  var currentThis = this;
  alert(this.id);
  e.preventDefault(); // breaks this
  alert(currentThis.id);
  etc etc
```

Comment: Should I then make a function inside of that so I can pass the variable? I need the variable for my post data.

Comment: Updated to provide ID of form that was `preventDefault()`

Comment: Great idea. Also, it is worth mentioning that you can always add more than one class for an element, like so:
    <form method="post" action="xxxx" id="yyy" class="someClass preventSubmit">

Comment: It says the `$(this).id` is undefined. I even did just checking it with alert and I checked that the class was right about five times.

Comment: That doesn't fix it. That actually keeps it from preventing default. Everything looks as it should I don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @qitch- this would have already worked for most cases. Post some of your markup. You're obviously doing something different and we won't be able to help if we don't see what it is.

Comment: @rgin and Erik. I got it to work with `$(this).attr('id')`  Erik you do ge tthe answer. I think you were right of course I don't know why it wouldn't work. Could it be a JQuery version problem?

Comment: Yeah. I _just_ posted that answer. Lol.

Comment: @qitch: good that you chose the correct answer, however you said that _there are many similar forms on the page that get generated dynamically_ .... and this answer (and example) works with existing forms but not with dynamically added forms. My five cents.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the submission itself, there are two approaches:

1) Use a input type="button" and attach a event handler for  click:

```
<input type="button" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />

// (In Javascript):

$("#submit_btn").click(function() {

});
```

2) To stop the submission, use return false :

```
$("#id" + variable).submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    var variable = $(this).attr('id');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: really sorry but that won't prevent a dynamically added form to be submitted

Comment: thanks for the down vote, however it would be nice if you leave a comment and prove me wrong first (if you can)

Comment: No it doesn't. But that's what is on his code, so I assumed it was how he wanted it. His question was about passing a variable via ID of the element. This is how you do it. :) Also, I did not downvote you. What made you say that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this `html`

```
<div id="wrap">
 <form id="id35">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
</div>
```

and this `js`

```
var threeFive = 35;
 $("#id"+threeFive).submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  alert("hi");
 });
```

it works!! ... **BUT**,  ...if you have this `html`

```
<div id="wrap">

</div>
```

and later you append dynamically the `form` element to the container, let's say like

*sample js function*

```
function addMe(){
 $('#wrap').append('<form id="id35"><input type="submit" value="submit" /></form>')
}
```

*sample add button*

```
<a class="addMe" href="javascript:addMe();">add form</a>
```

then, the example alert doesn't work anymore when you submit the `form`.

You would need to modify your script to support that dynamically added `form` using the `.on()` method (and jQuery v1.7.x) targeting the parent container like

```
var threeFive = 35;
$("#wrap").on("submit","#id"+threeFive, function(e){
 e.preventDefault;
 alert("hi");
});
```

then it will work

Comment: thanks for the down vote, however it would be nice if you leave a comment and prove me wrong first.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to deal with a lot of forms in single page, you might want to exploit bubbling.

```
<div class="container-for-all-forms">
<form id="..." class="..."> ..... <input type="submit" />  </form>
<form id="..." class="..."> ..... <input type="submit" />  </form>
<form id="..." class="..."> ..... <input type="submit" />  </form>
.
.
</div>
```

js bit might be

```
$('#container-for-all-forms').bind('click.formProcessor', function(event){
  var $clicked = $(event.target);
  if($clicked.is(':submit')){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($clicked.parents('form').attr('id'));

    /* at this point you can get all id names from php (or template language), bind js variables and match. like:
       var idNames = ['<?...?>','<?...?>']
    */

  }
});
```

this will bind only one event to container element, and you can run all sorts of checking when a click occurs in that container.